# What is terminlogy missing from this list of words and phrases pertaining to string-matching and string-alignment?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a long list of words/terms which are related to aligning one string to another.

- String Metric
- Edit-Distance
- Bioinformatics
- Needleman–Wunsch Algorithm
- Sequence Alignment
- Global Alignment
- Local Alignment
- Levenshtein distance
- Hamming distance
- Damerau–Levenshtein
- Jaro distance

Did I miss any? What would you add to the list?

Comment: This definitely has a bioinformatics flavour to it. You could do a lot worse than look for a review paper on sequence alignment such as this one: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9223667

Comment: This sounds to me like it might be too open-ended to be a good fit here.  The list of terms related to aligning strings might be lengthy.  See our [help/dont-ask], especially "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers".